# MeasureText not working correctly

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have a Bitmap object on which I want to draw some text. This text is supposed to be aligned right for a given point. This is how I do it right now:

```
newBitmap = Image.FromFile(bg) as Bitmap;
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);
var cvt = new FontConverter();

String temp = "ddddd"

ftemp = cvt.ConvertFromString("Times New Roman; 12pt") as Font;
SizeF p2Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(temp, ftemp);
p2Nick = new PointF(PosX - p2Size.Width, PosY);

g.DrawString(temp, ftemp, new SolidBrush(myColor), p2Nick);
```

The problem is the more text I enter for temp the bigger the distance from the right side gets.

[image]

Maybe someone can point out my mistake. Of course I simplified a lot but this is pretty much what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhhh, I love it... I was looking at my code for hours and couldn't find my mistake. Just went out for a few minutes came back and realized that I was doing some skewing after calculating the new position but I wasn't adjusting the new resolution to the calculated point.

I'm really sorry for asking this question -.-

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck using the same library to measure the string with that you're drawing with:

e.g.:

```
SizeF p2Size = g.MeasureString(temp, ftemp);
```

Also, the system's DPI text settings will affect the result, you can account for this by taking into account: Graphics.DpiX.

Finally, I think there is a setting `TextFormatFlags.NoPadding` that could help, but you'll be using `StringFormat` object instead if you switch to `Graphics.MeasureString()`.